# How to put Bearer Token into IFTTT Webhooks

Tags: api, firebase-cloud-messaging, webhooks, ifttt

I am trying to create a new automated api request and using IFTTT to it, to send an auto post request to Firebase Cloud Messaging service, but there is expected a Bearer Token as authentication in the header, and in IFTTT Weebhooks I can't change the header. How can I put my token in the body request or in url?